# C# vs C++ for loop performance measurment

Tags: c#, c++, performance, for-loop

For kicks, I wanted to see how the speed of a C# for-loop compares with that of a C++ for-loop. My test is to simply iterate over a for-loop 100000 times, 100000 times, and average the result.

Here is my C# implementation:

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {

    var numberOfMeasurements = 100000;
    var numberOfLoops = 100000;
    var measurements = new List < long > ();
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfMeasurements; i++) {
       stopwatch.Start();
       for (int j = 0; j < numberOfLoops; j++) {}
       measurements.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Average runtime = " + measurements.Average() + " ms.");
    Console.Read();
 }
```

Result: `Average runtime = 10301.92929 ms.`

Here is my C++ implementation:

```
void TestA()
{
    auto numberOfMeasurements = 100000;
    auto numberOfLoops = 100000;
    std::vector<long> measurements;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfMeasurements; i++)
    {
        auto start = clock();
        for (size_t j = 0; j < numberOfLoops; j++){}
        auto duration = start - clock();
        measurements.push_back(duration);
    }

    long avg = std::accumulate(measurements.begin(), measurements.end(), 0.0) / measurements.size();
    std::cout << "TestB: Time taken in milliseconds: " << avg << std::endl;

}

int main()
{
    TestA();
    return 0;
}
```

Result: `TestA: Time taken in milliseconds: 0`

When I had a look at what was in `measurements`, I noticed that it was filled with zeros... So, what is it, what is the problem here? Is it `clock`? Is there a better/correct way to measure the for-loop?

Comment: The loop was probably optimized away, since it is empty.

Comment: Clearly, C++ is much faster than C#. <g>

Comment: Put a counter in the loop and after you have stopped the clock print the value of the counter out.

Comment: @Galik Will be optimized to `counter = numberOfLoops;` by every sane compiler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no *"problem"*. Being able to optimize away useless code is one of the key features of C++. As the inner loop does nothing, it should be removed by every sane compiler.

Tip of the day: Only profile meaningful code that does something.

If you want to learn something about micro-benchmarks, you might be interested in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk).

Comment: I've also tried `num = num * j;`, yet the result is the same.

Comment: @pookie Again, only profile meaningful code. C++ compilers put a lot of work into eliminating useless code.

Answer (score 2):

As "Baum mit Augen" already said the compiler will remove code that doesn't do anything. That is a common mistake when "benchmarking" C++ code. The same thing will happen if you create some kind of benchmark function which just calculates some things that will never used (won't be returned or used otherwise in code) - the compiler will just remove it.

You can avoid this behavior by not using optimize flags like O2, Ofast and so on. Since nobody would do that with real code it won't display the real performance of C++.

**TL;DR** Just benchmark real production code.